# Use same form for new and updating record in visual c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-c#-express-2010

I am building a simple app in c# using Visual C# 2010 Express. I have created a data entry form which captures some data.

I'd like to use that same form for when a user wants to edit some data. How would I go about writing the code to tell the form that it's in edit mode, so load `recordID=4431`. If it's not in edit more, then just blank and add a new record when save is pressed.

Any thoughts?! 
Cheers, Matt.

Comment: What have you tried so far?  It would seem that a simple `bool`, or the presence/absence of the record ID, would be enough to say whether you're in edit mode or not.  Which part are you finding difficult?

Answer (score 3):

There a few ways of doing this. The simplest would be adding a `hidden field` to your form that would contain the ID of the object in edition, or null if it's a new submission.

Regards

Answer (score 1):

Well,

I have done this before. What I did was create a function that retrieves the data for specified record. This function will then just populate the fields in the form.

To tell the form it's in edit mode I just use a boolean to specify this. It is also necessary to store the record being edited so you can update it after.

Is this what your looking for or do you want code samples?

Comment: it sounds like this is the way forward.. so from my main form which calls the open function, I simply set a global bool to say it's in edit mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the form work like normal data-bound controls.

If you give it an entity that has it's members populated it fills in the fields accordingly.

Any fields that should not be user visible, like the id field, should be represented in the form as a hidden field.

Finally, your saving function should decide if it does an insert or update depending on if the primary key field(s) has a default value or not (usually 0).

Answer (score 0):

Well you can also overload the constructor of the form.
To do this you can pass form values as blank while inserting, & attach the values from database while in edit mode.

Hope this is useful.